# Why isn't my multithreading helping speedup?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I am reading lines of text into a list 'rows', and trying to use multithreading to speedup. However, it doesn't speedup at all. I am watching the cpu usage on my Mac, and noticed that cpu is 145% with multithreading, but no speedup.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

te = TimeExtractor()
def time_test(text):
    result = te.compute_time(text)
    # print(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    start = time.time()
    rows = []
    with open('data/data.csv', 'r', encoding='utf') as f:
        csvreader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in csvreader:
            rows.append(row['text'])

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as executor:
        results = executor.map(time_test, rows)

    end = time.time()

    print(end-start)
    print('Done!!!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified version of your code, using Multi-threading, is:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures
from multiprocessing import cpu_count

num_cpu = cpu_count()
print("CPU Count: ", num_cpu)  # cpu_count doesnt really matter
e = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(num_cpu)


def cpu_intensive_task(i):
    print(i, ' : start task')
    count = 10000000 * (i+1)
    while count > 0:
        count -= 1
    print(i, ' : end task')
    return i


start = time.time()
for i in e.map(cpu_intensive_task, range(10)):
    print(i, ' : in loop')
end = time.time()

print('LOOP DONE')
print('Total Time taken: ', (end-start))
```

Output:

```
CPU Count:  8
0  : start task
1  : start task
2  : start task
3  : start task
4  : start task
5  : start task
7  : start task
6  : start task
0  : end task
8  : start task
0  : in loop
1  : end task
9  : start task
1  : in loop
2  : end task
2  : in loop
3  : end task
3  : in loop
4  : end task
4  : in loop
5  : end task
5  : in loop
6  : end task
6  : in loop
7  : end task
7  : in loop
8  : end task
8  : in loop
9  : end task
9  : in loop
LOOP DONE
Total Time taken:  30.59025502204895
```

***Note*: Loop is exited only after all the threads are done**

Same code without Multi-threading:

```
import time


def cpu_intensive_task(i):
    print(i, ' : start task')
    count = 10000000 * (i+1)
    while count > 0:
        count -= 1
    print(i, ' : end task')
    return i


start = time.time()
for i in range(10):
    cpu_intensive_task(i)
    print(i, ' : in loop')
end = time.time()

print('LOOP DONE')
print('Time taken: ', (end-start))
```

Output:

```
0  : start task
0  : end task
0  : in loop
1  : start task
1  : end task
1  : in loop
2  : start task
2  : end task
2  : in loop
3  : start task
3  : end task
3  : in loop
4  : start task
4  : end task
4  : in loop
5  : start task
5  : end task
5  : in loop
6  : start task
6  : end task
6  : in loop
7  : start task
7  : end task
7  : in loop
8  : start task
8  : end task
8  : in loop
9  : start task
9  : end task
9  : in loop
LOOP DONE
Time taken:  30.072215795516968
```

***Note*: Time taken is almost same as Multi-threading approach (slightly lesser).
Multi-threading doesnt help this type of work load**

Same code using multiprocessing:

```
import time
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Value, cpu_count


def cpu_intensive_task(i):
    print(i, ' : start task')
    count = 10000000 * (i+1)
    while count > 0:
        count -= 1
    print(i, ' : end task')
    return i


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("CPU Count: ", cpu_count())
    start = time.time()
    processes = []
    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target=cpu_intensive_task, args=(i,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
        print(i, ' : in loop')

    print('LOOP END')
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
    end = time.time()
    print('Total Time Taken: ', (end - start))
```

Output:

```
CPU Count:  8
0  : in loop
1  : in loop
2  : in loop
3  : in loop
4  : in loop
5  : in loop
6  : in loop
7  : in loop
8  : in loop
9  : in loop
LOOP END
0  : start task
1  : start task
2  : start task
3  : start task
5  : start task
4  : start task
8  : start task
7  : start task
6  : start task
9  : start task
0  : end task
1  : end task
2  : end task
3  : end task
4  : end task
5  : end task
6  : end task
7  : end task
8  : end task
9  : end task
Total Time Taken:  10.335741996765137
```

***Note*: Multiprocessing takes just 1/3rd of the time taken for Multi-threading approach**

[Global Interpreter Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock):

> The mechanism used by the CPython interpreter to assure that only one
> thread executes Python bytecode at a time. This simplifies the CPython
> implementation by making the object model (including critical built-in
> types such as dict) implicitly safe against concurrent access.
> However, **some extension modules, either standard or third-party, are
> designed so as to release the GIL when doing computationally-intensive
> tasks** such as compression or hashing. Also, the GIL is always released
> when doing I/O.

[Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction):

> multiprocessing is a package that supports spawning processes using an
> API similar to the threading module. The multiprocessing package
> offers both local and remote concurrency, **effectively side-stepping
> the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads**.
> Due to this, the **multiprocessing module allows the programmer to fully
> leverage multiple processors on a given machine**.

So, only multiprocessing allows utilisation of multiple processors and hence true concurrency.

Comment: do you need to use "Lock" in your multiprocessing version code? You imported it but didn't use it in your code. Once somewhere it is locked, it might not be faster?

Comment: @marlon no the lock isn't used here. But locks are needed if two concurrently running functions want to access memory that is being mutated. If you can divide up the work before sending it to the workers then you don't need a lock, as long as the result is returned to a single collector.

Comment: On a separate note, I want to point out a caveat that the multiprocess approach being used here is not a good example of a scalable solution. You shouldn't use an unbounded number of processes to handle your inputs (in this case it is being capped to 10 for the demo). You want to either use a pool of fixed worker processes, or use a semaphore that will not let you launch a new process until the running count drops bellow the max again.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple possible angles to answering this question. CPython has something called the GIL (global interpreter lock) which prevents pure python code from running in parallel. This means that threads are really better suited to gains from i/o heavy code as opposed to cpu computations. This is because computations have far fewer points where they can block on i/o and release the GIL for other threads. The result is that a cpu intensive application will incur the cost of thread context switches without really getting any parallel performance increase.

If indeed you have a cpu bound function, your increases may be realized by batching up your work using multiprocessing instead of multithreading. Separate processes will be able to run in parallel and will incur a little more cost to serialize the input values. So the computation needs to outweigh the small serialization cost.

Beyond that, we would need to see exactly what your processing function is doing. You may even have a bug where you think you are splitting up your work but are not.